Efficiently Updating Matrix Multiplication Result When One Matrix Changes
Suppose you have two matrices $A \in Z_q^{m\times l}$ and $B \in Z_q^{l\times n}$, and the product $A\cdot B$ has already been computed. Now, matrix $B$ remains unchanged, but a few elements in matrix $A$ are modified (like updating some values, adding a new row, or deleting a specific row), resulting in a new matrix $A'$. How can we efficiently compute the updated product $A'B$ without recalculating the entire matrix product from scratch?

If $A' = A + E$ for $E$ sparse, then $A'\cdot B = A\cdot B + E\cdot B$, so you can simply compute $E\cdot B$ using a (sparsity-aware) matrix multiplication algorithm. That being said, it seems unlikely this is the right stackexchange site for this question.

Try moving question to https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/

Reposted on https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/44675/efficiently-updating-matrix-multiplication-result-when-one-matrix-changes
